# Getting apk from xamarin visual studio or emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am new to xamarin.
i am coding xamarin native android not xamarin forms.
I have issue connecting my android device to my xamarin visual studio suddenly.
As such,I am using emulator for my project right now but i need to get the apk so that i can load it into my android device.
How do i configure xamarin to create the apk in the project folder or extract the apk from the emulator?
There are many solutions for android studio but seems different for xamarin.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/android-archiving-and-publishing-made-easy/

Comment: thanks just asked my colleague a few minutes ago and got the answer but Build option must disable the shared mono

Answer (score 0):

You can do it over Tools / Archivemanager or just take the signed.apk in the bin directory.
If you use debug make sure you untick the use shared runtime checkbox.